# Необходимо сделать JOIN 2-х таблиц в одну

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Есть 2 таблицы:

1. LDR_IMMOBILI

   [EXTRACTION_ID],
   [BUILDING_NAME],
   [BUILDING_USE],
   [BUILDING_TYPE],
   [BUILDING_ACQ_COST],
   [BUILDING_MQ];
2. LDR_VENDITA_IMMOBILI

   [EXTRACTION_ID]
     ,[BUILDING_NAME]
     ,[BUILDING_SELL_DATE]
     ,[BUILDING_SELL_VALUE]
     ,[BUILDING_BUY_DATE]
     ,[BUILDING_BUY_VALUE]
     ,[BUILDING_MARKET_VALUE]
     ,[BUILDING_LEGAL_CONS_FIXED_VALUE]
     ,[BUILDING_LEGAL_CONS_VAR_VALUE]
     ,[BUILDING_MARKETING_SELL_COST]
     ,[BUILDING_AGENCY_COMMISSION]
     ,[BUILDING_AGENCY_SELL_VALUE]
     ,[BUILDING_AGENCY_COMMISSION_PERCENTAGE]
     ,[BUILDING_HIST_COST_VALUE]
     ,[BUILDING_HIST_COST_DATE]

Необходимо через INSERT и JOIN и колонки BUILDING_NAME заполнить с их помощью 3-ю:

3. BUILDING

   [EXTRACTION_ID] - PRIMARY KEY

   [BUILDING_ID] - PRIMARY KEY

   [BUILDING_NAME]
     ,[FUND]
     ,[BUILDING_USE]
     ,[BUILDING_TYPE]
     ,[BUILDING_ACQ_COST]
     ,[BUILDING_MQ]
     ,[SELL_BUILDING]
     ,[BUILDING_SELL_DATE]
     ,[BUILDING_SELL_VALUE]
     ,[BUILDING_BUY_DATE]
     ,[BUILDING_BUY_VALUE]
     ,[BUILDING_MARKET_VALUE]
     ,[BUILDING_LEGAL_CONS_FIXED_VALUE]
     ,[BUILDING_LEGAL_CONS_VAR_VALUE]
     ,[BUILDING_MARKETING_SELL_COST]
     ,[BUILDING_AGENCY_COMMISSION]
     ,[BUILDING_AGENCY_SELL_VALUE]
     ,[BUILDING_AGENCY_COMMISSION_PERCENTAGE]
     ,[BUILDING_HIST_COST_VALUE]
     ,[BUILDING_HIST_COST_DATE]

При этом, EXTRACTION_ID и BUILDING_ID будут сгенерированы сами, вот так:

```
DECLARE @Extraction_id bigint 
SELECT @Extraction_ID = format(getdate(),'yyyyMMddHHmmss')
DECLARE @Building_id int = 1 (АВТОИНКРЕМЕНТ)
```

Пробовал сделать всё через LEFT JOIN, но подозреваю, что это не правильно, и стоит использовать для этого INNER JOIN? Если возможно, подскажите пример кода, по которому можно будет написать свой.

Comment: почему вы подозреваете что left join не правильно, а inner правильно ? что нужно сделать то, как объединить. inner дает результирующую строку если в обоих таблицах есть подходящая по условиям строка. А left join дает строку в любом случае, когда в левой (относительно join) таблице есть строка, и вне зависимости от наличия строки в правой таблице. вот и все их отличие, так что решаете всегда давать строки или когда есть совпадение и действуете исходя из этого. И кстати, совершенно не понятно, зачем генерировать как то EXTRACTION_ID и BUILDING_ID если они есть в исходных таблицах

Comment: Так как BUILDING_NAME ни в одной из таблиц не является первичным ключом необходимо так же определиться, что делать если в какой то из таблиц более одной записи с одним BUILDING_NAME

Comment: И надеюсь вы понимаете, что если Extraction_ID указанного формата, то вы не сможете вставить в таблицу более одной записи в секунду

Comment: 1) если Extraction_ID указанного формата, то вы не сможете вставить в таблицу более одной записи в секунду - а если использовать numeric, а вставлять как bigint? Или же сразу изменить тип колонки на numeric в самой таблице?
2) не понятно, зачем генерировать как то EXTRACTION_ID и BUILDING_ID если они есть в исходных таблицах - building_id там нет, а что касается extraction_id, то это нужно для целей последующей работы с ними, то есть так должно быть.

Comment: Никакой разницы в каком типе данных это лежит нет. У вас поле в первичном ключе, если я правильно понял надпись primary key у двух полей, у вас композитный первичный ключ, состоящих из этих двух полей. А раз так, то в таблице не может быть более одной записи с одной комбинацией Building_id, Extraction_ID  А в своем примере вы им присвоили фиксированные значения, значит более одной записи с этими значениями вы все равно не вставите. И на фоне этого необходимость что то join-инить и вставлять сразу из других таблиц выглядит странно. Не вижу смысла выбирать из тех таблиц только 1 запись за раз

Comment: И вообще не принято полям _ID назначать дату в качестве значения, они обычно с потолка берутся (т.е. просто последовательные значения.)

Comment: Моя вина, @BUILDING_ID будет автоинкрементом. Забыл указать :(

Comment: Если BUILDING_ID автоинкремент, то тогда что означает надпись PRIMARY KEY у EXTRACTION_ID. Двух первичных ключей в таблице быть не может. А присоединение второго поля в первичный ключ, когда одно из них автоинкремент не имеет смысла, потому что первое уже заведомо уникально

Comment: EXTRACTIO_ID и BUILDING_ID - составной первичный ключ. Будет вот так:
1. 20171113152809 + 1
2. 20171113152809 + 2
3. 20171113152809 + 3 и т.д.

Comment: Какой смысл во втором поле в первичном ключе, если BUILDING уже само по себе уникально и его значение, если что, изменить и задать в ручную вообще невозможно (раз оно автоинкремент)

Comment: Есть в этом смысл, так как потом в эту же таблицу будут вставляться другие данные с другим EXTRACTION_ID, но BUILDING_ID будет отсчитыватся снова от 1

Comment: Это невозможно. Вы не можете управлять в ручную поведением автоинкрементного поля, оно будет гарантировано уникально на уровне БД

Comment: Либо оно у вас не автоинкрементно и значения для него вы создаете сами

Comment: А что касается основного вопроса, то общий вид запроса `insert into BUILDING(список колонок) select список колонок from LDR_IMMOBILI A join LDR_VENDITA_IMMOBILI B on A.BUILDING_NAME=B.BUILDING_NAME` собственно все, остальное зависит исключительно от того, чего же вы хотите получить в итоге и что совершенно не описано в вопросе

Comment: Это невозможно. Вы не можете управлять в ручную поведением автоинкрементного поля, оно будет гарантировано уникально на уровне БД - оно будет автоинкрементом на уровне SQL запроса, как то так:

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
INSERT INTO RealEstate_RiskEngine_DB.dbo.BUILDING(EXTRACTION_ID, BUILDING_ID)
 VALUES (\@Extraction_ID, \@Building_ID)

 SET \@Building_ID = \@Building_ID + 1

Comment: но это один insert, а вы хотите insert select что бы все сразу вставить, а тогда надо будет сделать просто `@Building_ID+row_number() over(order by какая-то-колонка)`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69067/discussion-between---and-mike).